# How to refresh a dictionary in a tkinter mainloop() in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am new to programming and I have been trying to understand when python/tkinter refresh values of dictionaries.

I've got the following code which basically creates a dictionary called states in which the item is linked to a value of 0.

I then launch the GUI.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

states = {'open_thermo':0}

def is_true(state): # in quotes
    states[state] = 1

def Station():
    Station = Tk()
    if states['open_thermo'] == True:
        Label(master=Station, text='Thermo has been opened').grid(row=0)
        Button(master=Station, text='press to end', command= lambda: combine_funcs(Station.destroy())).grid(row=4, columnspan=1, column=1, pady=4)
    else:
        Label(master=Station, text='Do you wish to open Thermo ?').grid(row=0)
        Button(master=Station, text='press to open Thermo', command= lambda: is_true('open_thermo')).grid(row=4, columnspan=1, column=1, pady=4)
        print states['open_thermo'] == True #1st print statement
    mainloop()

start = Tk()
Label(master=start, text='start').grid(row=0)
Button(master=start, text='press to start', command= lambda: combine_funcs(start.destroy(),Station())).grid(row=4, columnspan=1, column=1, pady=4)
mainloop()

print states['open_thermo'] == True #2nd print statement
```

I do not understand two things:

1. why the `print` statement commented as `#1st print statement` doesn't
   print over and over again before I click the button. I though
   `mainloop()` repeated the code above it over and over again.
2. why, when I click the button, the value of `states['open_thermo']`
   doesn't change to 1, and then the `if states['open_thermo'] == True:` statement becomes true because of `mainloop()`. I would expect
   the label to change to:

   ```
   Label(master=Station, text='Thermo has been opened').grid(row=0)
   Button(master=Station, text='press to end', command= lambda: combine_funcs(Station.destroy())).grid(row=4, columnspan=1, column=1, pady=4)
   ```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Tkinter can't know what code is above.  `mainloop()` is a function that keeps your program running while it is waiting for signals that are given to the window.  When you use `.bind()`, it is the `mainloop()` function that takes care of it.

Comment: Why are you destroying and recreating the root window? That is very unusual, and will likely cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: The reason for that is that I plan on doing a game where the user can choose between two options that each send him to another window. And I thought destroying the windows as I went was the best way to avoid the user being able to go back to previous windows and just start back from there.

Comment: Maybe you could hide the root window that keeps the program running with `root=Tk() ; root.withdraw()` then `start`, `station` etc. would be `Toplevel(root, ...)` widgets.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will look into that. Does anybody know why I can't get my if statement to become true once I have changed the value of states['has_thermo'] from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: You can simply delete all of the contents of the root window and replace it with your new content. Create two classes that inherit from `Frame`. Each class represents one of the windows. Then, pack one frame to fill the whole window. When switching, you just have to delete that one frame and then create the new frame. It is very simple and straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to programming and I have been trying to understand when python/tkinter refresh values of dictionaries.

python/tkinter never "refreshes values of dictionaries". The dictionaries change immediately when you tell them to change.

> 1. why the print statement commented as #1st print statement doesn't print over and over again before I click the button. I though mainloop() repeated the code above it over and over again.

No, `mainloop` does *not* repeat code that is above it. The code above it runs exactly once. `mainloop()` is a simple loop that waits for events and responds to them based on bindings. No code will run after `mainloop` until the window is destroyed.

> 2. why, when I click the button, the value of states['open_thermo'] doesn't change to 1, and then the if states['open_thermo'] == True: statement becomes true because of mainloop().

It's unclear which button you're talking about. However, it looks like both buttons that call `is_true` will actually change the value. I don't see any evidence that it doesn't. Since `is_true` doesn't do anything except change the value, I don't see how you think it's not changing.

Again, the code in `Station` runs exactly once when it is called. It doesn't run over and over and over. You click the button once, it is called once.